# MySQL Database design - Opinions

Tags: design, database, mysql

I'm working on a web application for our business with my brother. Our application is pretty simple, and will be developed with php and mysql.

- Clients and providers ABMs
- Articles Inventory (we do not manage stock, because we resell from our providers)
- Purchases
- Account balance for our clients and providers

I'm stuck on accounting tables... Here is my model:

[image: database design]
I'm in doubt about the account table; I'm thinking about use a trigger when purchases change Status (delivered to client) then updating the Account balance but I don't know if this model is good for managing Accounts for my Clients.

I'm looking for opinions about my mistakes!! Thank you.

Comment: 2 quick points, you are keeping what appear to be monetary amounts as floats not decimal and you might want to consider would you want to attach multiple addresses/phones/emails to a provider or client.

Comment: You are right, i will change data type on my table. All this information on Client table we use for purchases, many clients use differents ways to make a purchase (most rason is because they are from differents province) someone send us an email, or call us.. In providers i think its not necesary too much fields like clients...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Entity names should be singular (`client`, `purchase`, etc. not `clients`, `purchases`, etc. )
- Relationship from `purchase_article` to `purchase` should be one to many ( being `purchase` the one end )
- Relationship from `purchase_article` to `article` should be one to many ( being `article` the one end )
- Relationship from `provider_article` to `article` should be one to many ( being `article` the one end )
- Relationship from `provider_article` to `provider` should be one to many ( being provider the one end )
- `provider_article` Pk should be `(idProvider, idArticle)`, if you insist on using a surrogate then be sure to create an unique constraint on `(idProvider, idArticle)`
- What's the difference between `Phone` and `Telephone` ? Seems like violating 1FN to me
- What's the difference between `unitPrice` and `Price` ?
- Are you sure relationship between `Purchase` and `Account` is not inverted ?
- If you insist on having a surrogate PK on `client`, `provider`, etc., be sure to create unique constraint on business key to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Hi @user61852, Thanks for your comments. On response to your points: On my model I modified points 1-4 on relationship because I did it bad with Mysql Workbench. Purchase_article to Article doesnt exist anymore, now Its joined to provider_article. 7. Phone do reference to Cellphone and Telephone to an Local Phone at a physical place. 8. Purchase -> account were delete, now make reference on Client -> Accounts.

Comment: @JMHerrer If my answer was of any help, please vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't comment on minor details that you can fix later.
There are several structural issues here:

1. Why do you have a `PurchaseUnitPrice` in `Purchase`? This should be on `purchaseArticle`
2. Similarly why do you have a `PurchaseQuantity` in `Purchase`? This should also be on `purchaseArticle`
3. Some thing tells me `UnitPrice` is the price you got from the provider and `price` is the price you sell. If that is true, do NOT put in `article` the `profit`, if you want an argument, we can talk further to explain
4. Purchase status shouldn't be a boolean. You might want to have several options later such as 'unpaid', 'partial-paid', 'returned', etc
5. I assume you have a table `providerArticle` because an `article` might come from several providers. This way, make sure `PurchaseArticle` has a relationship with `ProviderArticle` not `Article` because you want to know the exact provider providing the article that you just sold. If my assumption is not true, simply make a many-to-many relationship between the `article` and the `provider`
6. `Account` should have a one-to-one relationship with `Client' not with`Purchase`
7. If you really want to keep track of the payments of each purchase, put a one-to-many relationship from `Purchase` to `Payment` (a new table entity)

Comment: Hi randomA, thanks for your reply! 3.You are right at this point. UnitPrice refer to provider price, and Price it is when i sell it to my clients. Where should i put Articles Profits?, and why should I move it from Articles Table. 4. Purchase status was modified to accept different options. 5. Ok, i understand. if I add an article ID it's could be from different provider and not from who exact sell me.. 6. Relationshio modified. 7. Payment table what function should do? Just track each order from each client with his payment ammount ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to to do a bit more analysis as to how time affects your model.

- An offer to sell is at the current price
- An item (or group of items) is sold at a particular price that won't ever change.
- You seem to be heading down the right track with the total price being in the purchases table, but then purchases_articles links to a table that has price and profit fields that may no longer be relevant.

What I am highlighting is that it is necessary to copy fields into "logging" tables, even though this looks like denormalisation. Classical data modelling theory tends to ignore this inconvenient reality..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the two foreign keys as a combined primary in providers articles.  This to make sure you only have one of each provider article. Otherwise you could get duplicates with just a different ID. And try to use human readable IDs (like email addresses). Besides that I don't really see anything besides maybe the decimal-float thing.